# AVAudioMixerNode gets automatically disconnected from destination node when calling AVAudioEngine.prepare()

Tags: swift, macos, avfoundation, avaudioengine

I am writing an audio sequencer application using Swift and Mac OS desktop. I user AVAudioMixerNode objects for generic routing and pass-through nodes (nodes where the audio just goes from point A to point B). The pass through nodes provide temporary "pit stops" in the audio chain where I can apply volume changes.

I have found that if you connect an AVAudioMixerNode to the AVAudioEngine's main mixer node, then call prepare, the mixer node gets automatically disconnected. There is no error or warning message. I have been ripping my hair out for four days trying to figure out why some nodes in my signal path were not connecting. Now I have written a simple Playground that proves definitively that this is the case.

```
import Cocoa
import AVFoundation


let engine = AVAudioEngine()
let mixer1 = AVAudioMixerNode()
engine.attach(mixer1)
let format = engine.mainMixerNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
engine.connect(mixer1, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: format)

var connections = engine.outputConnectionPoints(for: mixer1, outputBus: 0)
print("Number of connections = \(connections.count)")
engine.prepare()
connections = engine.outputConnectionPoints(for: mixer1, outputBus: 0)
print("Number of connections = \(connections.count)")
```

Answer (score 0):

The node is still present in the graph as evidenced by `print` but is in a pending state:

```swift
let engine = AVAudioEngine()
let mixer1 = AVAudioMixerNode()
engine.attach(mixer1)
engine.connect(mixer1, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: nil)
print("\(engine)")
engine.prepare()
print("\(engine)")
```

```
________ GraphDescription ________
AVAudioEngineGraph 0x10050bc70: initialized = 0, running = 0, number of nodes = 3

     ******** output chain ********

     node 0x600002c50f00 {'auou' 'ahal' 'appl'}, 'U'
         inputs = 1
             (bus0, en1) <- (bus0) 0x600002c51000, {'aumx' 'mcmx' 'appl'}, [ 2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved]

     node 0x600002c51000 {'aumx' 'mcmx' 'appl'}, 'U'
         inputs = 1
             (bus0, en1) <- (bus0) 0x600002c03b80, {'aumx' 'mcmx' 'appl'}, [ 2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved]
         outputs = 1
             (bus0, en1) -> (bus0) 0x600002c50f00, {'auou' 'ahal' 'appl'}, [ 2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved]

     node 0x600002c03b80 {'aumx' 'mcmx' 'appl'}, 'U'
         outputs = 1
             (bus0, en1) -> (bus0) 0x600002c51000, {'aumx' 'mcmx' 'appl'}, [ 2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved]
______________________________________



________ GraphDescription ________
AVAudioEngineGraph 0x10050bc70: initialized = 1, running = 0, number of nodes = 3

     ******** output chain ********

     node 0x600002c50f00 {'auou' 'ahal' 'appl'}, 'I'
         inputs = 1
             (bus0, en1) <- (bus0) 0x600002c51000, {'aumx' 'mcmx' 'appl'}, [ 2 ch,  48000 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved]

     node 0x600002c51000 {'aumx' 'mcmx' 'appl'}, 'I'
         outputs = 1
             (bus0, en1) -> (bus0) 0x600002c50f00, {'auou' 'ahal' 'appl'}, [ 2 ch,  48000 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved]

     ******** pending connections - output ********

     (bus0) 0x600002c03b80, {'aumx' 'mcmx' 'appl'} -> (bus0) 0x600002c51000, {'aumx' 'mcmx' 'appl'}, [ 2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved]
______________________________________
```

I suspect this is because there is no attached input or generator node although I haven't had a chance to experiment further.

Comment: Yes I tested that and it is true. It stays pending until it has a valid input source.

Comment: How do you normally drive the processing graph?

Comment: Sorry but your question is unclear. Can you please rephrase?

Comment: Without an input source the graph is  incomplete so the behavior exhibited in your question seems reasonable. How would you use a graph without an input source?

Comment: Because I want to be able to query the engine at any given time to determine which nodes are connected to which other nodes in order to display the right information on the mixing board. Otherwise I can have  situation where the mixer shows something as being connected, which in fact is not connected. For example, if your Send says "Bus 1" I want to know that it is really connected to Bus 1.

Comment: That makes sense.